# How to programmatically Pause the drawing of the Map?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#

In ArcMap, there is a button to [Pause the map's drawing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//006600000011000000). How do I programmatically call it from ArcObjects Code, before and after my heavy code runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IMxApplication2.PauseDrawing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//000v00000100000000) Property should be used.

It can be used as follows:

```
IMxApplication2 mxApp=(IMxApplication2) m_App;
mxApp.PauseDrawing=true;

//do your process here
mxApp.PauseDrawing=false;
m_app.RefreshWindow();
```